# MapsForge 0.4.0: is it possible to implelment a Marker 's onTap event?

Tags: android, events, click, marker, mapsforge

i'm using MapsForge latest branch (master) and i'd like to implement a Marker's onTap event.
I think it was possible on 0.3.0, but i can't use 0.3.0 because i use a different Drawable for each Marker on the map.

```
ArrayList<Monument> monuments = getMonuments(); 

mListOverlay = new ListOverlay();
ArrayList<OverlayItem> markers = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();          

for(Monument m : monuments){
    GeoPoint gp = new GeoPoint(m.getLat(), m.getLon());
    Marker m = createCustomMarker(R.drawable.marker, gp, p.getNumber()));
    markers.add(m);     
}

mListOverlay.getOverlayItems().addAll(markers);

mMapView.getOverlays().add(mListOverlay);
```

"createCustomMarker" returns a Marker that uses a Drawable with a number on top.

Anyone knows how i can override the behaviour of "m" when it is tapped?

Remember: branch master! not 0.3.0!!

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Create a class that inherits from Marker and overwrite onTab, the following way.
This solution checks if the tab was within the bounds of the Layer's bitmap (plus 10%).
If this is true the Runnable action will be called.

In Mapsforge each Marker is just a simple Layer which are stacked on top of the map. Each tab will call the topmost layer's ontab. If that returns false, the next topmost layer's ontab will be called, unless the function returned true or the last layer has been reached.

```
public class InfoMarker extends Marker {

    private Runnable action;

    public InfoMarker(LatLong latLong, org.mapsforge.core.graphics.Bitmap bitmap, int horizontalOffset, int verticalOffset) {
        super(latLong, bitmap, horizontalOffset, verticalOffset);
    }


    public void setOnTabAction(Runnable action){

        this.action = action;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTap(LatLong tapLatLong, Point layerXY, Point tapXY) {


        double centerX = layerXY.x + getHorizontalOffset();
        double centerY = layerXY.y + getVerticalOffset();

        double radiusX = (getBitmap().getWidth() / 2) *1.1;
        double radiusY = (getBitmap().getHeight() / 2) *1.1;


        double distX = Math.abs(centerX - tapXY.x);
        double distY = Math.abs(centerY - tapXY.y);


        if( distX < radiusX && distY < radiusY){

            if(action != null){
                action.run();
                return true;
            }
        }


        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: looks great. Gotta give it a try. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

To who it may concern, i've finally switched to OsmDroid, which can easily cover my needs.

For the onTap one, what i've done basically is:

http://mobiledevstories.wordpress.com/2014/03/01/osmdroid-bonus-pack-markers-with-clickable-infowindows/

Hope it saves time to someone!